# what is the energy required to change only direction of a vector?

Tags: energy, kinematics, work, vectors

Does change in velocity vector change Kinetic energy of a system?
Does any energy change when we change direction of a vector of a system?

Comment: You need to more specific. Benjamin gives a nice example where work is not required, but this is only because the force acts at right angle to the direction of motion. Depending on excatly what is changing and how work may or may not be required.

Comment: @JohnRennie edited the question.

Comment: Kinetic energy is a scalar, so if you change direction of the velocity but not its magnitude then the kinetic energy will not change. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Does no energy change if you change just direction of a vector?

Comment: Does no energy change if you change just direction of a 'velocity' vector?

Comment: @JohnRennie please help.

Answer (score 2):

The best example I can think of is *uniform circular motion* where the *speed* of revolution is fixed yet the *direction* of the velocity is tangent to the trajectory at any moment of time. For such a case, where the orbit is fixed a priori, there has to be some fixed centripetal force keeping the object in a circular orbit. This can be any type of force such as *tension* acting through a string (everyday life experiences) or *gravitational force* acting at distance with no contact (large scales). And this centripetal force does *no* work on the rotating object as it is *instantaneously perpendicular* to the trajectory.

Comment: I have edited the question to be  more specific to my confusion.